# how to insert/retrieve a userDefined Object in DB-MySql?

Tags: java, mysql

I want to insert and retrieve a  a user defined Object in DB,am using Mysql5.1.
1)What should me the data type for the column(is Blob is the correct answer for this question)

I am using EntityClass to Insert/Get values from the DB.
2)but to how to insert Object in database?

Comment: i am not sure if i understand the question correctly but i believe you can serialize your objects and store in the DB like you would store in flat file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common way is to translate the object to a table - every field of the object is (toughly) translates to a column of the table. The term for this is [object relational mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping). There is plenty of documentation of this on the web (like [this](http://www.developer.com/java/data/article.php/3391131/An-Introduction-to-Object-Relational-Mapping-with-Hibernate.htm)) as this is one of the cornerstones of modern day enterprise development.

There are several libraries you can use, and the best is to stick to the standard called JPA - [Java Persistence API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API).  The most known libraries (all open source) are

- [Hibernate](https://www.hibernate.org/)
- [EclipseLink](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/)
- [OpenJPA](http://openjpa.apache.org/)

Your user defined object will look like this :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "some_table")
public class SomeObject implements Serializable {

    static final long serialVersionUID = <some value>;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    protected Long id;

    @Column
    protected String name;

    @Column
    protected int value;

    // default constructor
    // getters, setters
    // equals, hashCode, toString
    // other methods
}
```